# Error 406 Not Acceptable when generating PNG response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have a problem with method generating PNG image responses.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/thumb/{id}.png", produces = "image/png")
@ResponseBody
public char[] thumb(@PathVariable UUID id)
{
    // action logic here

    return CatalogController.PLACEHOLDER_THUMB;
}
```

However I can't access this action - it is executed correctly (I see logic effects in database), but client gets **406 Not Acceptable**.

Here is how I simulate the request (same happens in Chrome and Internet Explorer):

```sh
$ wget "http://localhost:8080/thumb/13164e6b-fc0f-4c67-a7d3-e2c56224384b.png" -O - --header="Accept: image/png"
--2013-11-18 18:37:30--  http://localhost:8080/thumb/13164e6b-fc0f-4c67-a7d3-e2c56224384b.png
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 406 Not Acceptable
2013-11-18 18:37:30 ERROR 406: Not Acceptable.
```

## Edit

Here is more detailed description displayed in browser:

> description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ().

Comment: Did you try adding a "Accept : image/png" header to your request?

Comment: I believe the 406 means that the request's accept headers are not applicable to what is being produced in the response.  You may have to doctor your request to send the appropriate accept header.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that with wget.  Also, I don't see where you are setting the mime type on the response at all.  You should be setting that.

Comment: Check my `wget` command line.

Comment: wget --header="Accept : image/png"

Comment: @CodeChimp: Content type is set with `produces` attribute of `@RequestMapping` annotation. If it wouldn't be set response would work completely fine (I guess), just displayed incorrectly as text, but it's just not rendered at all by server. For `wget` I know how to set the header, and this is intentionally there to show that even with correct `Accept` header it doesn't work :(.

Comment: @EJK: No, headers should not have spaces after them. And just in case you would insist on checking this out: `wget: --header: Invalid header `Accept : image/png'.` ;).

Comment: You still have not answered the very first question - What is the behavior when you include in your response, an "Accept" header with a value of image/png?

Comment: @EJK: Response? `Accept` is a request-header.

Comment: Yes I meant request header.  What is your answer to the question?

Comment: @EJK: Please, check to question again - this header is there from the very beginning, this is what I pasted to explicitly show that client accepts specified content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for everyone for helping, but the answer is far more trivial - it's simply not possible to use `char[]` as response content.

Switched to `byte[]` and everything worked fine!

(probably could be possible to register handler for `byte[]` but it's not needed for me, so can't confirm that).